# How to stop testRunner in case one of the http APIs HTTP Status Code is not 200

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am running on an CI machine my soapUI automation solution, invoked by testRunner.sh.

is is invoked as following:

```
/Projects/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/testrunner.sh ~/sautomation_work/Automation_Project.xml
```

I would like to stop the whole process in case a certain API http status code is not 200.

Any ideas ?
currently, the only way I can do this is by invoking the last test suite "FinalReport" and disable rest of the test scripts currently available in the running test suite.

The code is as following:

```
public testSuiteStop() {
    def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap();
    def reportTestCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Report").getTestCaseByName("FinalReport");
    reportTestCase.run(properties, true);
    def testSuite = context.testCase.testSuite;
    def totalTestCases = testSuite.getTestCases().size();
    for(testCaseItem in (0..totalTestCases-1)) {    
        testSuite.getTestCaseAt(testCaseItem).setDisabled(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have SoapUI-Pro you could create a custom event. In the free version, your solution is about as good as you are going to get.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will further investigate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to exit the current soapUI execution in case one of the critical test has already failed.
The idea is to disable the remaining test suites and test cases, and execute a "final" test suite that reports the failed test execution.

my code looks like this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase;

WsdlTestSuite testSuite = context.testCase.testSuite;
WsdlProject project     = context.testCase.getProject();

// Disable remaining test cases in the current test suite.
for (WsdlTestCase testCase in testSuite.testCaseList) {
    testCase.setDisabled(true);
}

// Disable rest of the test suites
for (WsdlTestSuite testSuiteName in project.testSuiteList) {
    testSuiteName.setDisabled(testSuiteName.name != "LastTestSuite");
}
```